# Deployment of EMET causes 20% of all users to have issues with office and internet explorer

Tags: windows-7

We are having an issue where, after deploying EMET we noted that about 20% of our users are having problems when using Office or Internet Explorer. The one thing that solves the issue is if an administrator logs onto the machine. The administrator does not have to do anything but logging onto the workstation (no other action than a simple logon).

After this the problem goes away. Has anyone else had this issue before?